# http delete user with Auth0 apiv2

Tags: angular, auth0, http-delete

I am trying to delete a user based on id, on auth0 API v2 they give only the curl command.  For the post method I managed to adapt it to angular2 http post, for some reason I cannot figure out how to use the delete request.

the id looks like this

```
id = auth0|582b40627882b2970253725c
```

This is the method I am using:

```
deleteAuth0User(id){
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer mytoken');
return this.http.delete('https://myusername.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users/' + id, {headers:headers})
.map(response => response.json());
}
```

I have removed my auth0 username and api token.

I get this error as a result:

```
"{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Insufficient scope, expected any of: delete:users,delete:current_user","errorCode":"insufficient_scope"}"
```

Any suggestion much appreciated.
Thank you

P.S. If you are interested in the post method for adding a new user:

```
createAuth0User(body){

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer myapitoken');
    return this.http.post('https://myusername.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users', JSON.stringify(body),{headers:headers})
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

Comment: Avram, pleased you sorted it out! Have dropped in a quick "answer" to suggest an easy way to get template code too.

Comment: or rather you can create a singleton token generation method to use the same token within the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, with the Auth0 API v2 each time you add to the scope an option  a new token is generated, you can add multiple options to the scope so you can use the same token for all of them.

The 2nd thing with the Auth0 API v2  on http delete you cannot use .map because you will get a:

```
json parsing error syntax error unexpected end of input
```

The working method is:

```
deleteAuth0User(id){
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer mytoken');
return this.http.delete('https://myusername.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users/' + id, {headers:headers})
}
```

This will work, do not forget to subscribe in the component you are using the method because you will still get a response back.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to get the code you require is by using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Then you can simply import the Curl command into Postman (using `import` option) and / or generate the required JavaScript (client side) / NodeJs code (using Postman's `code` option).

See screenshots below:

[image]

and

[image]

Finally, you can get pre-built template Postman commands for all Auth0's [Authentication API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication)  and [Management APIv2](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2) endpoints.

See the downloads options [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/info)